# How to solve a coupled, non-linear stochastic differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am an experimental physicist and I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$ z'' + w_0^2 z + c_1 z^3 - c_2 y = 0$$
$$ y'' + c_3y' + w_0^2 y + c_4\delta(t) + c_5 z' = 0$$

These equations represent a system of two coupled oscillators, where one is non-linear ($x$) and the other is damped and noise-driven ($y$).

All coefficients $w_0$ and $c_i$ are real and constant, $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac-Delta function.
As final result I am interested in the time-average of the Fourier Transformation of $y'(t)$.

I am a bit overwhelmed by the combination of coupled, non-linear and stochastic. Where do I start here? Is this even analytically attainable?

Comment: A solution is impossible for $c_1\ne 0$. You can simulate it numerically if $y(t)=z(t)=0$ for $t<0$. Then you get initial conditions for the solution at $t\ge 0$ of $z(0)=z'(0)=y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=-c_4$.

Comment: what is stochastic here?

Comment: @LutzLehmann ok, $c_1$ is small, is a pertubative approach possible?

Comment: @user619894 $c_4\delta(t)$ shall note that $c_4$ is randomized for every step in time, aka its drawn from a Gaussian distribution with a certain width.

Comment: If that is your attempt to define white noise,  you better find a proper SDE formulation for the randomness if you want to get a result that is, at least statistically, independent of the numerical method. // Note that $δ(t)$ is the point mass at $t=0$. Did you intent discrete pulses, $\sum f_k\delta(t-t_k)$?

Comment: if  "All coeffieicents <...> $c_i$ " are constant then how is $c_4$ randomized? Please add this to the question.